# I want to get the Ip address of android Phone and how can I Contact that android phone from web server Using that Ip address to get some Information?

Tags: android

I want to get the IP address of Android Phone, for this I tried InetAddress but I got the IP address 127.0.0.1 on Emulator. How can I get the actual IP address .
Secondly I want to contact that android mobile using that IP address from a web server for asking some Information like its position.
For eg:Suppose Phone1 wants information of Phone2 then Phone1 contacts webserver and webserver contacts phone2 using its saved ip address and then phone2 responses with its location to webserver and webserver respond to phone1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code for getting IPV4:

```
private String getLocalIpAddress() {
       try {
           for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
               NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
               for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                   InetAddress in`enter code here`etAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                   if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                       if (inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                           return ((Inet4Address)inetAddress).getHostAddress().toString();
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       } catch (SocketException ex) {
           Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
       }
       return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the server asking the phone for its position, try to think the other way.

Create an app which will run on the phone and regularly will send its position to your server. Then when Phone 2 wants to know the position of Phone 1, it'll get the latest known position from the server.

Comment: It will fill up my database with lat lang, I want only ip address of device to be updates whenever it changes,and I want asynchronous call when the request comes from phone1 then only phone2 must be contacted for location.

Comment: not necessarily fills up your database, since you have not to store every position, only the most recent.

Comment: Thanks But i was trying to implement it different way

Answer (score 0):

found here: http://www.droidnova.com/get-the-ip-address-of-your-device,304.html

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
try {
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
            InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
            if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException ex) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
}
return null;
}
```

> So if this method returns null, there is no connection available.
>   If the method returns a string, this string contains the ip address currently used by the device independent of 3G or WiFi.

Comment: I have used this code also it gives me the IP address 10.0.2.15 on emulator, will it give the correct IP address when it will run on actual device.

Comment: I think so, yes. Be aware of NAT (router etc.).

Comment: And How can I access Information from android phone using that IP address

Comment: maybe like this: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-connection-example-part-ii-tcp-communication

Comment: Thanks for Help I must try It first

Comment: Should I make a socket server for It or should I make a service to respond to request on android phone